# Удалить из строки запрещенные символы

Tags: php

Есть ли в `PHP` функция, которая удаляет из строки все символы, запрещенные в имени файла?

Comment: https://webformyself.com/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-kak-udalit-chto-to-iz-stroki/

Comment: Проще оставить только разрешенные, нежели составлять огромный перечень запрещенных...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И проще и лучше, чем другой вариант. Писать список запрещенных символов, это, конечно, сильно..вместо того, чтобы просто разрешить допустимые. В данном случае буквы a-z, а-я, точка и цифры 0-9 + регистры букв. В результате будет:

`teTt12.png`

```
$string = '`#@!&$&!@teTt12.png';
$result = preg_replace('/[^ a-zа-я\d.]/ui', '', $string );
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего использовать для решения задачи регулярные выражения.
Список запрещенных символов, которые я использую: `\/:*?"<>|+%!@`.

В PHP использовать метод `preg_replace`:

```php
$string = 'some'
$forbidden = '\/:*?"<>|+%!@';
$stringWithoutForbiddenCharacters = preg_replace("/[${forbidden}]/", '', $string);
```